# Can someone help me create an Up Button in action bar

Tags: android

Im developing an application where the home view will use dashboard design. I saw in android design pattern that they introduce a new concept of using Up Button. Im confuse a little bit cause up button and back button is always the same except that you can use Up button to go directly in your home view. Can someone tell me how to create an Up Button in action bar sherlock? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: you mean a the home  button in an action bar?

Comment: ahm yeah. or something like iphone back button which is in the upper left part. is it posible?

Comment: just call finish() in your onClick() if you want to make a button act like iphone back button

Comment: so how to implement it in actionbar??

Comment: have you already succeed to add the action bar sherlock in your layout and add some menu item?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have already implemented the action bar, you should be able to set up home button using the following code.

**This in the onCreate**

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**This as a separate method**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intentHome = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
            intentHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intentHome);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This should work, if it's the same thing your trying to do.

Comment: To use the actionBar before Honeycomb (3.0), you can use actionBarSherlock (a 3rd party support library), or use the updated android support package from Google. http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use/ This link will show you how to set it up in your project.